# Angular 4 Output() with dropdown

Tags: angular

Getting started with angular (v4), trying to create a reusable component that simply contains a drop down. But couldn't pass its selected value to a component that uses it via `@Output()`. Please see plunker example [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/VNhTb2/)

Essentially, this is the reusable component:

```
import { Component,  Output, EventEmitter, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-group-selector',
  template: `
    <div>
      <label>Group</label>
      <select [ngModel]="selectedgroup" (ngModelChange)="onGroupChanged($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let groupName of groupNames" [ngValue]="groupName">{{groupName}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>`
})
export class SharedComponent {
  @Output() selectedgroup: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  groupNames: string[];
  constructor() {
    this.groupNames = ['A', 'B', 'C'];  
    this.selectedgroup = 'A';
  }


  onGroupChanged(newvalue): void {
    console.log(newvalue);
    this.selectedgroup.emit(newvalue);
  }

}
```

Here is how I want to use it in another component (app component):

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {SharedComponent} from 'src/shared.component';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Test</h2>
      <app-group-selector (selectedgroup)='onSelectedGroupChanged($event)'></app-group-selector>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  selectedGroup:string;
  constructor() {
    //this.name = ""//`Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  onSelectedGroupChanged(newgroup):void {
    this.selectedGroup = newgroup;
    console.log(newgroup);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, SharedComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Clearly the problem is with `<app-group-selector (selectedgroup)='onSelectedGroupChanged($event)'></app-group-selector>`
The error I got on plunker is **`instance[output.propName].subscribe is not a function`**. On my machine I got a different error (probably due to not using the latest version of angular though I am still using v4): **`ERROR TypeError: this.selectedgroup.emit is not a function`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error itself is this line in your shared component:

```
this.selectedgroup = 'A';
```

You initially set `this.selectedgroup` to be a `new EventEmitter<string>()`, but here you're replacing it with a string value `'A'`.

You have a more general problem where you're trying to use `this.selectedgroup` as both the `EventEmitter` and the `ngModel` value.

EDIT: I've forked and edited your original example [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/2aRclnlsJeTERyd1h3YX/).

Comment: thanks. On a related question, how to access the `ngModel` in the shared module (e.g. the initialised selected group) from the consuming component (e.g. app component here) before selection changed event is triggered? For example, I need to do something in the consuming component based on the initial selection.

Comment: One option would be to use `ngOnInit` in your `SharedComponent` and then you could perhaps call `onGroupChanged(...)` or `emit` directly in there. If that's not clear, perhaps search SO or ask a new question.

Comment: That's exactly what I did e.g. calling `emit` in `ngInit` on the shared component. But how to receive it in the consuming component? I feel I am so close to it...

Comment: Got it. I was being silly to think I can access the initial shared `ngModel` from `ngInit` on the consuming component, whereas should access it from the event handler. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Modified the `SharedComponent` to this,

```
export class SharedComponent {
  @Output() selectedgroup = new EventEmitter<string>();
  groupNames: string[];
  selectedGroup: string;
  constructor() {
    this.groupNames = ['A', 'B', 'C'];  
    this.selectedGroup = 'A';
  }
 onGroupChanged(newvalue): void {
    console.log(newvalue);
    this.selectedgroup.emit(newvalue);
  }

}
```

It worked on plunker. Notice the new property, `selectedGroup` used for the `ngModel` assignment on the shared component template.

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue was that you were setting the same property (`selectedgroup`) of `SharedComponent` that you intended to be your `EventEmitter`, equal to a string, "A".

I separated out your model (now `name`) from your `EventEmitter`, and things now log quite nicely. Relevant code below, with a working plunk [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/wngSlw/).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-group-selector',
  template: `
    <div>
      <label>Group</label>
      <select [(ngModel)]="name" (change)="onGroupChanged(name)">
        <option *ngFor="let groupName of groupNames" [value]="groupName">{{groupName}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>`
})
export class SharedComponent {
  @Output() selectedgroup: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  groupNames: string[];
  // note new property here, to be used as ngModel
  name: string;
  constructor() {
    this.groupNames = ['A', 'B', 'C'];  
    this.name = 'A';
  }

  onGroupChanged(newvalue): void {
    console.log('from Shared:',newvalue);
    this.selectedgroup.emit(newvalue);
  }
}
```